# What are the risks associated with keeping woodlice at home?

Tags: animal-handling

I have started collecting woodlice in the garden and putting them in plastic boxes (with small holes, ~ 1 mm wide) with rotten leaves, pieces of apple and earth. What are the risks associated with keeping them in the house? Could they or their offspring escape and start an infestation in my house? Do they carry diseases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short blurb from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse):

> **Woodlice as pests**
>
> Although woodlice, like earthworms, are generally considered beneficial in gardens for their role in controlling pests, producing compost and overturning the soil, they have also been known to feed on cultivated plants, such as ripening strawberries and tender seedlings.
>
> Woodlice can also invade homes en masse in search of moisture and their presence can indicate dampness problems. They are not generally regarded as a serious household pest as they do not spread disease and do not damage sound wood or structures.

If they escape, they may get into any compost you house indoors, possibly garbage, and may identify leaks in your house :)